# splitting str into int and then turning into a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to concert a list which has words and and points score next to it into a dictionary
the list looks roughly like this `("oliver34", "jack17" , "jane56")`
I want to split this into `("oliver", "34" "jack" , "17" , "jane", "56"`
so that I can turn them into a dictionary.
if this can be done without importing anything that would be preferable

sorry if this does make sense first time using stack overflow and im not good at coding

Comment: What about names [that contain numbers](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried input.split([i]) which did nothing and just failed

Answer (score 0):

If the variables inside the list always have the same format which is **a name followed by a number**, then you can just do this:

```
def text_num_split(item):
for index, letter in enumerate(item, 0):
    if letter.isdigit():
        return [item[:index],item[index:]]
```

Comment: sorry I missed your response, are index item and letter all variables simple question i'm just trying to figure out how your code works as I said very new to coding

Comment: item would be your list of names and index is just helping us to go through your list and splitting the names and numbers